# How to add a "first login page"?

Tags: angular

Do you think it is possible to create a first login page for the user? This page will disappear after a second connection

Currently, I have 2 pages on my website:

When the user arrives on the login page, he enters his user id (first page)

[image]

```
<!-- CONNECT EXPLAINED -->
<div class="mb-4" *ngIf="fase == 1">
  <div class="row align-items-center mb-5">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
      <div class="step-number">
        <span class="numberIcon">A</span>
        <p>
          Enter your User Id
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 text-center text-sm-right">
      <input type="text" class="customInput" [(ngModel)]="user">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row align-items-center mb-3">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
      <div class="step-number">
        <span class="numberIcon">B</span>
        <p>
          You can record your User Id on this computer by checking this box.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 text-center text-sm-right">
      <div class="d-inline-block">
        <label class="customCheckbox" (click)="rememberme()" [ngClass]="{'checked': rememberMe}">
          <span class="icon"></span>
          <span class="titleIcon">
            Record the code
          </span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row align-items-center mb-5">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
      <div class="step-number">
        <p class="mentions">
          Warning. Do use this option only on your personnal computer. Don't use it if you  connect through a public or shared computer.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row align-items-center mb-5">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
      <div class="step-number">
        <span class="numberIcon">C</span>
        <p>
          Click on Submit.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 text-center text-sm-right">
      <button class="customButton" (click)="goToFase(2)">
        Send
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row align-items-center mb-5">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
      <div class="step-number">
        <span class="numberIcon">D</span>
        <p>
          Only if your DIGIPASS is blocked, click Unblock.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 text-center text-sm-right">
      <button class="customButton" (click)="goToUPUK()">
        Unlock
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
      <p class="mentions">
        You do not yet have access to XXXXXXXXX please contact us on freephone number (XXXX) XXX.XXX  Access to XXXXXXXXXXX is entirely free!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
      <p class="mentions">
        
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- FIN CONNECT EXPLAINED -->
```

Then, he arrives on the second page

[image]

```
<!-- DIGIPASS EXPLAINED -->
<div class="mb-4" *ngIf="fase == 2">
  <div class="d-flex d-md-none flex-column align-items-center">
    <div class="image-fixed mb-5">
      <img src="/assets/images/digipass-explained.png">
    </div>
    <div>
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="phase2"></ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-none d-md-flex flex-nowrap align-items-center">
    <div class="image-fixed mr-4">
      <img src="https://zupimages.net/up/21/32/585x.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="phase2"></ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<ng-template #phase2>
  <div class="row align-items-center mb-3">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
      <div class="step-number">
        <span class="numberIcon">A</span>
        <p>
          Switch on your Digipass by pressing the button with the red arrow.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-center mb-3">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
      <div class="step-number">
        <span class="numberIcon">B</span>
        <p>
          Enter your PIN Code in your Digipass.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-center mb-3">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
      <div class="step-number">
        <span class="numberIcon">C</span>
        <p>
          Your Digipass requests you which application you want to user. Press 1.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-center mb-3">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
      <div class="step-number">
        <span class="numberIcon">D</span>
        <p>
          Enter the number in 6 digits delivered by your Digipass.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 text-center">
      <input type="text" class="customInput" [(ngModel)]="otp">
      <div class="error">
        <div *ngIf="otp?.length > 6 ">
          code OTP invalide
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="otp?.length > 0 &&  otp?.length < 6">
          code OTP invalide
        </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="success">
        <div *ngIf="otp?.length == 6">
          code OTP valide
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-center mb-3">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
      <div class="step-number">
        <span class="numberIcon">E</span>
        <p>
          Click on Connect:
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 text-center">
      <button class="customButton" (click)="signin()"  [ngClass]="{'success': otp?.length == 6 ? true : false}">
        Connect
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
<!-- FIN DIGIPASS EXPLAINED -->
```

If the user has never visited my site previously, I would like to add several texts on the second page. (just for a first user connection)

Here is an idea of the page that I would like to display:

[image]

Honestly, I don't really understand how to create a mechanism to add of the text according to the user's first connection.

My code is created like this:

```
<!-- CONNECT EXPLAINED (first page )-->
<div class="mb-4" *ngIf="fase == 1">
  <div class="row align-items-center mb-5">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
      <div class="step-number">
        <span class="numberIcon">A</span>
        <p>
          Enter your User Id
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 text-center text-sm-right">
      <input type="text" class="customInput" [(ngModel)]="user">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row align-items-center mb-3">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
      <div class="step-number">
        <span class="numberIcon">B</span>
        <p>
          You can record your User Id on this computer by checking this box.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 text-center text-sm-right">
      <div class="d-inline-block">
        <label class="customCheckbox" (click)="rememberme()" [ngClass]="{'checked': rememberMe}">
          <span class="icon"></span>
          <span class="titleIcon">
            Record the code
          </span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row align-items-center mb-5">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
      <div class="step-number">
        <p class="mentions">
          Warning. Do use this option only on your personnal computer. Don't use it if you  connect through a public or shared computer.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row align-items-center mb-5">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
      <div class="step-number">
        <span class="numberIcon">C</span>
        <p>
          Click on Submit.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 text-center text-sm-right">
      <button class="customButton" (click)="goToFase(2)">
        Send
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row align-items-center mb-5">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
      <div class="step-number">
        <span class="numberIcon">D</span>
        <p>
          Only if your DIGIPASS is blocked, click Unblock.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 text-center text-sm-right">
      <button class="customButton" (click)="goToUPUK()">
        Unlock
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
      <p class="mentions">
        You do not yet have access to XXXXXXXXX please contact us on freephone number (XXXX) XXX.XXX  Access to XXXXXXXXXXX is entirely free!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
      <p class="mentions">
        
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- FIN CONNECT EXPLAINED -->

<div class="firstText" style="font-size: 20px; padding-bottom: 15px;">This is your first connection to XXXXX.</div>

<div class="secondText" style="padding-bottom: 60px;">In order to guarantee the confidentiality of your acces toXXXXXX, we will ask you to introduce a first number generated 
by your Digipass, then to choose a personal question ....
</div>



<!-- DIGIPASS EXPLAINED  (second page)-->
<div class="mb-4" *ngIf="fase == 2">
  <div class="d-flex d-md-none flex-column align-items-center">
    <div class="image-fixed mb-5">
      <img src="/assets/images/digipass-explained.png">
    </div>
    <div>
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="phase2"></ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="d-none d-md-flex flex-nowrap align-items-center">
    <div class="image-fixed mr-4">
      <img src="https://zupimages.net/up/21/32/585x.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="phase2"></ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<ng-template #phase2>
  <div class="row align-items-center mb-3">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
      <div class="step-number">
        <span class="numberIcon">A</span>
        <p>
          Switch on your Digipass by pressing the button with the red arrow.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-center mb-3">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
      <div class="step-number">
        <span class="numberIcon">B</span>
        <p>
          Enter your PIN Code in your Digipass.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-center mb-3">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
      <div class="step-number">
        <span class="numberIcon">C</span>
        <p>
          Your Digipass requests you which application you want to user. Press 1.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-center mb-3">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
      <div class="step-number">
        <span class="numberIcon">D</span>
        <p>
          Enter the number in 6 digits delivered by your Digipass.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 text-center">
      <input type="text" class="customInput" [(ngModel)]="otp">
      <div class="error">
        <div *ngIf="otp?.length > 6 ">
          code OTP invalide
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="otp?.length > 0 &&  otp?.length < 6">
          code OTP invalide
        </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="success">
        <div *ngIf="otp?.length == 6">
          code OTP valide
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-center mb-3">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
      <div class="step-number">
        <span class="numberIcon">E</span>
        <p>
          Click on Connect:
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4 text-center">
      <button class="customButton" (click)="signin()"  [ngClass]="{'success': otp?.length == 6 ? true : false}">
        Connect
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
<!-- FIN DIGIPASS EXPLAINED -->
```

If you have an idea, I am interested to know how to do this.

Comment: That's a ton of superfluous information for what I think the question is, but based off of what I think the question is, you can use localstorage and authguard https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the login page should allow anyone to access it, authorised or not.

The user logs in. The backend responds with the setCookie response header.
This causes the cookie to be sent in all subsequent requests.

Your backend server then checks for the presence of the cookie in all subsequent HTTP requests.

If the cookie is absent the server responds 401.

Use an Angular HTTP interceptor to redirect to the login page on any 401s.

On the login page, if the user is already logged in, you could add some logic inside ngOnInit to redirect to another route. To support this, the server should provide an /is-authorised endpoint or a /whoami endpoint.